# Javascript | Filtering in nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, filter

I need to filter the following data, with the text that the user types inside an input, but only in 3 keys (date, pizza and size)

```
  var pizzaData = [{
    "id": 1,
    "date": "2020-03-20",
    "order": [
      {"pizza": "chicken", "comment": "No onion", "size": "personal"}, 
      {"pizza": "cheese", "comment": "", "size": "medium"}
    ]}, {
    "id": 2,
    "date": "2020-03-21",
    "order": [
      {"pizza": "veggie", "comment": "Extra cheese", "size": "big"}
    ]}, {
    "id": 3,
    "date": "2020-03-22",
    "order": [
      {"pizza": "Pepperoni", "comment": "", "size": "big"},
      {"pizza": "Double cheese", "comment": "", "size": "big"},
      {"pizza": "BBQ chicken", "comment": "", "size": "small"},
      {"pizza": "Mushrooms", "comment": "", "size": "big"}
    ]}, {
    "id": 4,
    "date": "2020-03-25",
    "order": [
      {"pizza": "cheese", "comment": "", "size": "small"}
    ]}
  ]
```

I'm using angularjs, I've tried using $filter, creating a filter and also filter method in js, but I can only get the first object inside "order" array.
The code should work in Chrome, Mozilla and Explorer 11

I'm trying to achieve something like this

```
input = "cheese"

pizzaData = [{
    "id": 1,
    "date": "2020-03-20",
    "order": [
      {"pizza": "chicken", "comment": "No onion", "size": "personal"}, 
      {"pizza": "cheese", "comment": "", "size": "medium"}
    ]}, {
    "id": 4,
    "date": "2020-03-25",
    "order": [
      {"pizza": "cheese", "comment": "", "size": "small"}
    ]}
  ]




input = 2020-03-21

pizzaData = [{
    "id": 2,
    "date": "2020-03-21",
    "order": [
      {"pizza": "veggie", "comment": "Extra cheese", "size": "big"}
    ]}
  ]



input = onion

pizzaData = []
```

Comment: Show your filtering code.

Comment: you want exact pizza name or matching part of pizza name eg: cheese ,Double cheese both pizza name contains cheese

Answer (score 0):

You can create a string of all the values that you want to search in, in each order and check for the searched key in that string.

```js
  var pizzaData = [{
    "id": 1,
    "date": "2020-03-20",
    "order": [
      {"pizza": "chicken", "comment": "No onion", "size": "personal"}, 
      {"pizza": "cheese", "comment": "", "size": "medium"}
    ]}, {
    "id": 2,
    "date": "2020-03-21",
    "order": [
      {"pizza": "veggie", "comment": "Extra cheese", "size": "big"}
    ]}, {
    "id": 3,
    "date": "2020-03-22",
    "order": [
      {"pizza": "Pepperoni", "comment": "", "size": "big"},
      {"pizza": "Double cheese", "comment": "", "size": "big"},
      {"pizza": "BBQ chicken", "comment": "", "size": "small"},
      {"pizza": "Mushrooms", "comment": "", "size": "big"}
    ]}, {
    "id": 4,
    "date": "2020-03-25",
    "order": [
      {"pizza": "cheese", "comment": "", "size": "small"}
    ]}
  ]
  
  function getOrder(key) {
    return pizzaData.filter((eachOrder) => {
      let text = [eachOrder.date];
      text = text.concat(eachOrder.order.map(({pizza, size}) => ([pizza, size])));
      return text.join(' ').includes(key);
    })
  }
  
  console.log('2020-03-21 => ', getOrder('2020-03-21'))
  console.log("cheese => ", getOrder("cheese"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var pizzaData = [{
    "id": 1,
    "date": "2020-03-20",
    "order": [
      {"pizza": "chicken", "comment": "No onion", "size": "personal"}, 
      {"pizza": "cheese", "comment": "", "size": "medium"}
    ]}, {
    "id": 2,
    "date": "2020-03-21",
    "order": [
      {"pizza": "veggie", "comment": "Extra cheese", "size": "big"}
    ]}, {
    "id": 3,
    "date": "2020-03-22",
    "order": [
      {"pizza": "Pepperoni", "comment": "", "size": "big"},
      {"pizza": "Double cheese", "comment": "", "size": "big"},
      {"pizza": "BBQ chicken", "comment": "", "size": "small"},
      {"pizza": "Mushrooms", "comment": "", "size": "big"}
    ]}, {
    "id": 4,
    "date": "2020-03-25",
    "order": [
      {"pizza": "cheese", "comment": "", "size": "small"}
    ]}
  ]


function search(data){
  let searchData=[];
  if(data.split("-").length==3){
    for(var i=0;i<pizzaData.length;i++){
        if(pizzaData[i].date==data){
          searchData.push(pizzaData[i]);
        }
    }

    return searchData;
  }


  for(var i=0;i<pizzaData.length;i++){
      let orders=pizzaData[i].order;
      for(var j=0;j<orders.length;j++){
         if(orders[j].pizza.toLowerCase().match(data.toLowerCase()) || orders[j].size.toLowerCase().match(data.toLowerCase())){
            searchData.push(pizzaData[i]);
         }
      }
  }

    return searchData;


}

console.log(search("2020-03-21"));
console.log(search("cheese"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var pizzaData = [{
"id": 1,
"date": "2020-03-20",
"order": [
  {"pizza": "chicken", "comment": "No onion", "size": "personal"}, 
  {"pizza": "cheese", "comment": "", "size": "medium"}
]}, {
"id": 2,
"date": "2020-03-21",
"order": [
  {"pizza": "veggie", "comment": "Extra cheese", "size": "big"}
]}, {
"id": 3,
"date": "2020-03-22",
"order": [
  {"pizza": "Pepperoni", "comment": "", "size": "big"},
  {"pizza": "Double cheese", "comment": "", "size": "big"},
  {"pizza": "BBQ chicken", "comment": "", "size": "small"},
  {"pizza": "Mushrooms", "comment": "", "size": "big"}
]}, {
"id": 4,
"date": "2020-03-25",
"order": [
  {"pizza": "cheese", "comment": "", "size": "small"}
]} ]

 const searchData = keywords => {
  const filteredData = pizzaData.filter(pizza => {

const filteredOrder = pizza.order.filter(({pizza, size}) => {
  return (pizza === keywords || size === keywords)
})

return (pizza.date === keywords || !! 
  (filteredOrder.length))

   })
    return filteredData
 }

  console.log(searchData('small'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answers are great, I'm sharing my try. I'm using `filter` function and inside that using `some` to detect any match case(on order):

```js
var pizzaData = [{
    "id": 1,
    "date": "2020-03-20",
    "order": [
      {"pizza": "chicken", "comment": "No onion", "size": "personal"}, 
      {"pizza": "cheese", "comment": "", "size": "medium"}
    ]}, {
    "id": 2,
    "date": "2020-03-21",
    "order": [
      {"pizza": "veggie", "comment": "Extra cheese", "size": "big"}
    ]}, {
    "id": 3,
    "date": "2020-03-22",
    "order": [
      {"pizza": "Pepperoni", "comment": "", "size": "big"},
      {"pizza": "Double cheese", "comment": "", "size": "big"},
      {"pizza": "BBQ chicken", "comment": "", "size": "small"},
      {"pizza": "Mushrooms", "comment": "", "size": "big"}
    ]}, {
    "id": 4,
    "date": "2020-03-25",
    "order": [
      {"pizza": "cheese", "comment": "", "size": "small"}
    ]}
 ];
  
let filterPizza=(filterData)=>{ 
result=pizzaData.filter((value)=> value.date == filterData || value.order.some((elem)=>elem.pizza.toUpperCase()==filterData.toUpperCase() || 
elem.size.toUpperCase()==filterData.toUpperCase()))
return result;
}
console.log(filterPizza('cheese'));
console.log(filterPizza('2020-03-21'));
```